# Momentjs saving month ahead

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm working with momentjs, I receive the correct object but when I try to save it saves a month ahead, I tried to subtract months which worked fine for others months, but when I try to save 'december' I got an error, 'invalid date', obviously because it tries to save month 13, that doesn't exist.

Received Object in the same Method

```
Object { day: "12", month: "01", year: "2017", formatted: "12-01-2017", momentObj: Object }
```

When I try to save in that same Method

```
Object { uid_date: "killerengel_12-02-2017", name: "task1" date: "12-02-2017"}
```

What I use to save:

```
let chosenDate = moment(task.date).utc().format('DD-MM-YYYY'); //this gives me a month ahead

Object { day: "30", month: "12", year: "2017", formatted: "30-12-2017", momentObj: Object } 

Object { uid_date: "killerengel_Invalid date", name: "task2", date: "Invalid date" }
```

Comment: not sure if momentjs matches native javascript, but a notorious flaw of doing times/dates in js is that the months are zero based while everything else is one based

Comment: what is `task.date`? are you using a localisation setting in momentJS?

Comment: @deweyredman
I feel stupid, I used the formatted and it worked, BUT as you said it is zero based, so when probably I will find some other errors when I try to make calculations using the dates strings and MomentJS, (ex. know which date comes before, but I can manipulate the strings to do that).
Btw I'm using jkuri/ng2-datepicker which is not zero based, I thought the error was from moment, so I will ask him if it will not render others errors.
Anyway should I delete this question, or wait for and moderator to close it? I don't know I'm new here, that was my 1st question.

Comment: @haxxxton task.date was the 1st object received which I tried to save the date on the Firebase.

Comment: momentjs is pretty good at detecting dates from a string. if you can hand it something like "30-01-2017" itll know that 01 in this context represents january. worst case momentjs lets you specify the format the input string is in (to handle US vs British date ordering) using its second parameter ie `moment("30-01-2017", "DD-MM-YYYY")` if you can concatenate your object values you shouldnt need to adjust anything to get moment to correctly identify the month :)

Answer (score 3):

@deweyredman is right. For the JavaScript Date() function, January is 0 and December is 11. This is similar to the fact that arrays start at 0 for their indexing. Do you think Moment.js works the same way?

```js
var jan = new Date().setMonth(0); // NOT 1 for Jan.

console.log(new Date(jan)); // returns 2017-01...

var dec = new Date().setMonth(11); // NOT 12 for Dec.

console.log(new Date(dec)); // returns 2017-12...
```

Comment: You are correct, see: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/ -- "Note that like moment(Array) and new Date(year, month, date), months are 0 indexed."